# how can i show the hidden content in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide all the content and show some content as the user click.

In anchor tag I used 'scr' before its `id` example: `scrhome_screen`.

But in `div` tag that I want to show has id `home_screen`.

Please explain why it is not working?

```
hideAll();
showTab("home_screen");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id.substring(0, 3)=="scr"){
        hideAll();
        showTab(id.substring(3,id.length));
    }
  });
});

function hideAll(){
  $('#home_screen').hide();
  $('#sec_screen').hide();
  $('#third_screen').hide(); //this is working
  // document.getElementById("home_screen").style.display = "none"; 
  // document.getElementById("sec_screen").style.display = "none";
  // document.getElementById("third_screen").style.display = "none";
}

function showTab(divName){
  console.log(divName);
  $('#'+divName).show(); // it think this line is not working
}
```

----------edit-------------------
my html code

```js
hideAll();
showTab("home_screen");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id.substring(0, 3)=="scr"){
        hideAll();
        showTab(id.substring(3,id.length));
    }
  });
});

function hideAll(){
  $('#home_screen').hide();
  $('#sec_screen').hide();
  $('#third_screen').hide(); //this is working
  // document.getElementById("home_screen").style.display = "none"; 
  // document.getElementById("sec_screen").style.display = "none";
  // document.getElementById("third_screen").style.display = "none";
}

function showTab(divName){
  console.log(divName);
  $('#'+divName).show(); // it think this line is not working
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MENU STARTS HERE -->
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#" id='scrhome_screen'>Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">New/Open Project</a>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a href="#" id='scrsec_screen'>New Project</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id='scrthird_screen'>Open Project</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Region</a>
    <!-- <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu 3</a></li>
            </ul> -->
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Insurance Indices</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Insurance Scheme</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- HOME STARTS HERE -->
<div id="home_screen">
  <div id="description">
    <fieldset>
      <p class="descriptionHead">Crop-loss Assessment Monitor Toolbox (CAM)</p>
      <p id="descritionText">CAM toolbox is specifically designed to estimate prevented sowing, sowing failure and yield loss occurring in a geographical area. The tool has been also embedded with financial viability analytics which determines farmers’ premium, maximum claim,
        claim ratio etc. The CAM tool can also be used to test the important indicators to assess the feasibility of an insurance scheme. Moreover, loss assessment from multiple methods also enables a comparison of risk coverage under different technologies
        and their subsequent effect on the economics of the insurance scheme.</p>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <hr id="ver_line" width="1" size="200">

  <div id="login_signup">
    <fieldset>
      <p class="descriptionHead">LOGIN</p>
      <form>
        <p id="loginBody">
          <input type="text" class="loginForm" placeholder="Login Id"><br>
          <input type="password" class="loginForm" placeholder="Password"><br>
          <input type="submit" class="loginButton" value="LOGIN"><br><br>
      </form>
      Not registered?<br>
      <a id="registerBtn"><input type="button" class="loginbutton" value="Register here"></a>
      <br>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 2nd FIELDSETS -->
<div id="sec_screen">
  <p>another content is here</p>
</div>

<!-- 3rd FIELDSETS -->
<div id="third_screen">
  <p>third content is here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `id.substring(3,id.length)` might not return what you expect.
try `id.split("scr")[1]`

Comment: Using `.split()` method makes your life a bit more bearable. Vouch for @Adelin

Comment: i checked it in console. its giving right string.

Comment: Or just `id.substring(3)` which goes to the end

Comment: And instead of `id.substring(0, 3)=="scr"` better use `id.indexOf("scr") == 0` or `id.startsWith("scr")`

Comment: yes i will change it but it is going in if condition with substr() // so lets ignore that for a sec. thank you

Comment: Besides all of the "helpful" micro optimisation tips, there's nothing obviously wrong with your code - can you you include some HTML, specifically the `a` and `div` pair?  Maybe try to make it into a snippet.

Comment: last advice, instead of superfluous `if` and string tampering, why not pass the element directly? Like `showTab($(this));` and in `showTab` drop the hashtag `$(divName).show()` (all these advices are because those steps I tend to improve are error prone)

Comment: Here's a fiddle with your code (minus the start show) and it works fine, so must be something else somewhere else that you've not included:  https://jsfiddle.net/e2cnf7xv/

Comment: Well, if we're giving advice, then give your `a` a class so that you don't have to search for "scr" and give your divs a class so they don't have to be hidden 1by1.  Then use `data-` pair to match the two and **drop all the string processing completely**.  *But that's not the question here.*

Comment: This `<li><a href="#" id='scrhome_screen')>Home</a></li>` paranthesis is unwanted, it may be the reason. And then again `<li><a href="#" id='scrthird_screen')>Open Project</a></li>`

Comment: Updated the fiddle by adding your html, removed head/body tags and, despite all the html errors, it still works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/e2cnf7xv/2/

Comment: The `)` has no impact (at least in Chrome)

Comment: yes it is working fine!!! thanks there is css problem i got that

Answer (score 0):

In your code this `<li><a href="#" id='scrhome_screen')>Home</a></li>` paranthesis is unwanted, it may be the reason. And then again `<li><a href="#" id='scrthird_screen')>Open Project</a></li>`

Here is another mistake

```
<form>
  <p id="loginBody">
    <input type="text" class="loginForm" placeholder="Login Id"><br>
    <input type="password" class="loginForm" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="submit" class="loginButton" value="LOGIN"><br><br>
</form>
Not registered?<br>
<a id="registerBtn"><input type="button" class="loginbutton" value="Register here"></a>
<br>
</p>
```

Tags are closed in the wrong order

Your js works, I did not change anything.

By the way in `.substr` you can just do `id.substring(3)` instead of `id.substring(3,id.length)`

```js
hideAll();
showTab("home_screen");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (id.substring(0, 3) == "scr") {
      hideAll();
      showTab(id.substring(3,id.length));
    }
  });
});

function hideAll() {
  $('#home_screen').hide();
  $('#sec_screen').hide();
  $('#third_screen').hide();
}

function showTab(divName) {
  $('#' + divName).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="home_screen">home_screen</div>
<div id="sec_screen">sec_screen</div>
<div id="third_screen">third_screen</div>

<a href="#" id="scrhome_screen">home_screen</a>
<a href="#" id="scrsec_screen">sec_screen</a>
<a href="#" id="scrthird_screen">third_screen</a>
```

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: i cleared my cache n all but its not working for my code can you pls check my code

Comment: @freedomn-m I did :)